# Handling arrays of C structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a C 
struct of the form :

```
#define RGB_TYPE 1
#define YUV_TYPE 2
#define MAX_LIST 20


typedef struct
{
    uint16_t a[2];
    uint8_t b;
    float_t c;

} mystruct;
```

I have an array of mystruct  like this

```
 mystruct MyStructList[MAX_LIST]=  {
       {{100, 200}, RGB_TYPE, 25.0},          
       {{200, 400}, RGB_TYPE,25.0}, 
       {{300,600} ,YUV_TYPE ,30.0},
           {{400,600},YUV_TYPE, 30.0}


};
```

In my code I do the following ;

```
 mystruct config;
 int i = 0;

 .....
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    config = MyStructList[i];
    /* further processing on config */
  some_func(i,&config);

}


int  some_func(int x, mystruct* pstruct );
{
        /* using pstruct values and storing them in internal arrays */
 }
```

Is this sort of struct copy and handling valid ?
    I am using mingw gcc

Comment: `struct`s are assignable, so `config = MyStructList[i];` is fine. Any other doubts?

Comment: i fail to see any error, but i dont know what ur goal is. do you need 'config' if your are gonna assign it to other 'MyStructList[i]'
you could just do some_func(i,&MyStructList[i])

Comment: "using pstruct values and storing them in internal arrays" Which internal arrays are you storing the pstruct values to? And when you says "pstruct values" do you mean the pointer that is passed to `some_func` or the values of the structs `pstruct` points too?

Comment: By the way, you can replace the magic number `4` with `sizeof(MyStructList) / sizeof(*MyStructList)`.  Then the loop will automatically adjust itself if you add or remove items from MyStructList.

Answer (score 2):

It looks OK, but note that `config = MyStructList[i];` makes a shallow copy of the struct.  If you want to operate on the original array, mystruct should be a pointer that takes the address of MyStructList[i].

For example:

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  mystruct * config = &MyStructList[i];
  some_func(i, config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying `config = MyStructList[i];` you should allocate the number of elements needed by using `malloc`.  For example, in the loop body, you should say

```
mystruct * config = ( mystruct *) malloc ( i * sizeof ( mystruct ) );
some_func ( i, config );   // You do not have to use address because config is a pointer type now
free ( config );
```

Comment: **Dat kast to `mystruct *`!!**

Comment: ("You should" - why should he, by the way? Using automatic variables is fine...)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of copy is valid. It might not be efficient, you could just use a pointer to the original struct when calling some_func(). Then in some_func you store a copy of it's values in internal arrays.